# Perl packet crafting and injection module

Tags: perl, network-programming, packet-capture

Could someone provide if there are a perl packet crafting and injecting module that works on windows xp sp2 or windows vista ,
if not could someone provide which libraries i need to build such tool ?

Answer (score 2):

Try out the [`Net::Pcap`](http://p3rl.org/Net%3a%3aPcap) Perl module.

Comment: Ok Thanks could you if possible show me how can i craft and inject  packet with net::pcap ?

Answer (score 0):

[Scaperl](http://sylv1.tuxfamily.org/projects/scaperl.html) ([Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) for Perl) is a toolkit for packet capture, construction, manipulation, and injection.

Comment: The scaperl link is dead. Google turns up some hits, but not immediately clear which is the definitive official home page.